# Mounting NTFS partition: old fstab cached?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, fstab, ntfs

Ubuntu 22.04, dual booting with Windows 10 with a shared NTFS drive for data storage. Using Dolphin as my default file manager.

A long journey down the rabbit hole into fine tuning the mounting options for my shared partition (for reasons that are beyond the scope of this posting) has culminated in manually setting up my mounting configuration for my NTFS partition (`/dev/sda2`) in `/etc/fstab` (with `auto` option for auto mounting on startup).

After switching from the default "stock" mounting procedure to my customized one, I noticed that Dolphin had stopped showing folder previews within the shared NTFS partition. A quick search led to an easy fix for that issue: substitute the FUSE based `ntfs-3g` mounter with the native `ntfs3` one. That worked (after dropping `nls=utf8` from my `fstab` entry) and I got my folder previews back in Dolphin after a hot unmount/mount sequence.

However, after rebooting, I lose folder previews again. Unmounting and remounting fixes the problem, which leads me to the following questions:

- Is the boot/startup mounting procedure cached?
- Is it possible that the startup mounting of my NTFS partition is still using `ntfs-3g`?
- How can I force startup mounting to abide by the `fstab` configuration?

My `fstab` line:

`UUID=xyz /media/me/DATA ntfs3 rw,auto,users,exec,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,gid=1000,uid=1000,windows_names    0   0`

Comment: In answer to your 3 points: No. Yes, maybe - check your system logs `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. `/etc/fstab` is already the One True Source of mounting information.

Comment: If your Windows has "Fast Boot" enabled, it will leave the disk in a state Linux doesn't understand. Turn off Windows' "Fast Boot".

Comment: @waltinator Fast Boot is off in Windows. Always has been.

Comment: @waltinator Yes, it didn't make sense for the `fstab` configuration to be cached. Please check my answer below.

Comment: @waltinator please don't post answers as comments. That circumvents the quality control system of the site (voting) and can discourage others from posting actual answers which means the question might never be counted as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some more digging and a stroke of luck, I think I figured it out!
The thing is (and I had omitted this information from the original post because I had completely forgotten about it), prior to going through the `fstab` route, I had tried setting up an auto-mount of my shared NTFS partition using a `systemd` service unit (that was placed in `/etc/systemd/system/`). I was trying to "replace" the automounter configuration without changing the mount point because of existing links and bookmarks. Now my `systemd` unit had the following directives:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount DATA

[Mount]
What=/dev/sda2
Where=/media/me/DATA
Type=ntfs
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the service's filename was as required: `media-me-DATA.mount`

After initially fiddling around with that option, I decided to ditch the attempt and go through `fstab` instead. I disabled the service (`systemctl disable media-me-DATA.mount`) but left the file hanging in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory.

Fast forward to `fstab` mounting where I used the same mounting point as the aforementioned service, and following a reasonable deduction that it seems that the automounter goes through `systemd` by apparently creating an "on-the-fly" service behind the scenes, and it was obvious that a conflict was occurring. When the automounter was detecting an existing service unit with the right name, it was enabling and activating it instead of creating a new one using the configuration from `fstab`. And with the existing service configured to use `defaults`, the conflict was causing the partition to be automounted via `ntfs-3g` instead of `ntfs3`.

So the fix without having to sacrifice the mounting point was simply to remove the "hanging" `media-me-DATA.mount` file from `/etc/systemd/system` and all works as intended now. Startup automounting now follows the `fstab` configuration and mounts through `ntfs3`, and Dolphin shows folder previews for the shared NTFS partition at startup.